# M2: getBaseUrl() - StoreManagerInterface vs StoreConfigInterface

Tags: magento2, best-practice, base-url, code-analysis

If someone asks for getting base URL, the answer is always to use `StoreManagerInterface`, like ...

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
...
$this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

It works, but it breaks PHPStan code analyzation.

```
  104    Call to an undefined method                              
         Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface::getBaseUrl().
```

**Question**

Isn't it better to use `StoreConfigInterface` instead?

```
protected $storeConfig;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreConfigInterface $storeConfig
) {
    $this->storeConfig = $storeConfig;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
...
$this->storeConfig->getBaseUrl();
```